# GetKeyNameText returns name in uppercase

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I have a `TextBox` which is displaying the key name for individual keys - to display a hotkey combination. For example "Alt + Ctrl + T".

I have the following method which is called from `PreviewKeyDown` on a `TextBox`.

The string returned is the correct name for the key. The problem is when I press Ctrl + Shift this seems to toggle the case of the returned string from `GetKeyNameText` (Interestingly I have tried entering Ctrl + Shift keys on other third party apps that let you define hotkeys and they have the same issue.

```
public string KeyToString(Key key)
{
    StringBuilder sbString = new StringBuilder(256);

    uint virtualKeyCode = (uint)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(key);

    // Gets the layout of keyboard
    IntPtr keyboardLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);

    // Map the virtual keycode
    uint scanCode = MapVirtualKeyEx(virtualKeyCode, 0, keyboardLayout);

    // Get Text
    GetKeyNameText(scanCode << 16 | (1 << 25), sbString, sbString.Capacity);

    return sbString.ToString(); ;
}
```

Comment: What is `Key`?  Is that one of the properties of the `PreviewKeyDownEventArgs` from the `PreviewKeyDown` event?

Comment: Yes, everything works it's just that the returned text from `GetKeyNameText` can be toggled to upper case after pressing `Ctrl + Shift`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out - thanks.

I have different keyboard layouts loaded (ENG-US and ENG-INT) and I noticed that `Ctrl + Shift` toggles which layout I'm using - ENG-INT has the key names in upper case.

The only reference to this I found is here [disable ctrl shift for layout](https://superuser.com/questions/109066/how-to-disable-ctrlshift-keyboard-layout-switch-for-the-same-input-language-i)